# How to query for multiple sub strings with position in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query:

```
select position( '/s/' in col)
from table
```

This works.

Now, I want to be able to find the position of `/s/` or `/d/` or `/c/`

I tried:

```
select position( '[/s/][/c/][/d/]' in col)
from table
```

But it returns a wrong value.

Example:

```
select position( '/s/' in '/s/')
```

returns 1.

```
select position( '[/s/][/d/][/c/]' in '/s/')
```

returns 0

How can I solve this?

Edit:

- It can contains only one of `/s/` or `/d/` or `/c/`.  The string will not contain `/s/d/` etc...
- There can't be more the one occurrences of the matched sub-string. The string won't contain `'/s/..../s/'`

In simple words - I'm looking for the first occurrence of `/s/ or /d/ or /c/` don't worry about the edge cases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name prestodb running over amazon.

Comment: What if `col` contains both `/s/` and `/d/`? Does it matter which position to return if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @RuudHelderman it won't. It can contains only one of them. It's indenture that it contains only one occurrence of such.

Comment: Are you sure you can use patterns there? If yes, try `position('/s/|/d/|/c/' in '/s/')`.

Comment: @stickybit doesn't work. I need a way to make it work other than write different position query for each sub-sring :(

Comment: Do you just want to know if any of the substrings are in there or is it important to know the exact position?

Comment: @stickybit One of them must be there (no need to check) I just want to know the position of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote in the comments, that only one of the substrings will be present and `position()` returning `0`, if the substring isn't found, you just can check the sum of multiple `position()`s.

```
SELECT position('/s/' in col)
       +
       position('/d/' in col)
       +
       position('/c/' in col)
       FROM table;
```

Or even nicer, since Presto has a `greatest()` function, you could do:

```
SELECT greatest(position('/s/' in col),
                position('/d/' in col),
                position('/c/' in col))
       FROM table;
```

Like that you get the greatest position.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this solution but wanted to know if there is a way to avoid the multiple position queries.. I have like 15 of theses :(

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT MAX(patlist.pattern) FROM (VALUES (POSITION('/s/' IN col)), (POSITION('/d/' IN col)), (POSITION('/c/' IN col))) AS patlist(pattern)
```

Wrapped inside a query:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(patlist.pattern) FROM (VALUES (POSITION('/s/' IN col)), (POSITION('/d/' IN col)), (POSITION('/c/' IN col))) AS patlist(pattern))
FROM MyTable
```

Disclaimer: in absence of a prestodb instance, I could only test it on an alternate database engine. It may or may not work on prestodb.